# DataGridView Doesn't show ShortTime record

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using a DataGridView that gets its data from table in Microsoft Access, one of the fields is a Short Time type record (e.g 16:00) but when the DataGridView is loaded it shows the record as "16:00 12/31/1899" and never shows only the ShortTime.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

The datagridview doesn't look at the original type to do its formatting. If the system type was a timespan instead of a datetime, a default time formatting was used. Perhaps you can influence the binding?

In any rate, you can always override any default formatting by using the [CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event of the datagridview (see link for example)

**edit** oops, forgot to mention the easiest way: set the format of the defaultcellstyle of a column (can be done in designer):

```
   YourDataGridView.Columns["NameOfTimecolumn"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
```

Comment: @user1461085 if this solved your problem, click the holo tickbox next to this answer and you will earn a couple of points.